# plot.ly python graph url

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plot.ly to plot some graphs on some data. The graph is shown correctly but I would like to get a url to the graph that is hosted on plot.ly/username/xxx. Is there a way to get the url programmatically? I checked the plot.ly documentation but did not come across this option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default when creating plot. The URL are passed by the function

```
import plotly.plotly as py
url = py.plot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

Comment: thanks, I figured it out by looking at the documentation just now